How do I gray out the service startup type for my own windows service? (The service is written using win32 API )
I am writing a service, in which I want to restrict users from modifying service startup type. How do I do? I have attached a windows service which grays out the startup option.
WinDefend - Service Properties:


You would have to start a user level service as a system user. I cannot in good conscious help you with this endeavor.

Is "graying out" the real goal? Or is the intent to disable changing the startup type? The Win32 registry has fine-grained security. Just don't give users write access to the startup type.

Yes, the goal is to restrict user to modify the service startup type. For now, I know the key can be restricted so when user tries to modify the service startup it will show up error. But is there a way to gray out via API like restricting to control the service status (stop, start and pause)

AFAIK, there is no public API to allow a user service to grey out its startup type. Microsoft does that for their own system services so users don't mess up the OS. If you don't want users to stop/pause your service, you can handle that in your service code by omitting the SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE and SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP controls when calling SetServiceStatus().

I also want user to not modify the service startup type too

Actually, it's more about service data, see SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO and CreateService but there is no public API. You can also use Access Rights for a Service to get the same effect.
